# Why docker sleep 1 for continuous background process?

Tags: docker

I would like to do "starting a long-running worker process" as in this article
https://docs.docker.com/articles/basics/

I don't understand why sleep 1? why not sleep 86400??? one day or one year?

```
# Start a very useful long-running process
$ JOB=$(sudo docker run -d ubuntu /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo Hello world; sleep 1; done")

# Collect the output of the job so far
$ sudo docker logs $JOB

# Kill the job
$ sudo docker kill $JOB
```

What's the "best" way to make it run as a background process for apache, nginx, mysql etc?

Why do you need to echo? is that necessary?

Answer (score 1):

This job is to write `Hello world` to stdout every second I guess for demonstration purposes only.  If you want to do something else at some different interval you have to change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing is the `-d` flag makes Docker run it in background ('detatched'), and the `docker logs` lets you examine the logs as many times as you like after that point.

For Apache, get hold of an Apache image; for Nginx use an Nginx image, and so on.

I found [this image with Nginx and PHP](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/maxexcloo/nginx-php/), and [the official Docker mysql image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) worked for me.  You'll need to do a bit more reading to see how to integrate your data, web content, config, etc.